# How to create new dataframe by tokenizing contents of existing dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am very new to python/pandas and need help from the community. Here is what I am trying to do.

I have read a json file which contains following data:

1. Contents(of an article)
2. ID (unique identifier)
3. Title (Title of the article)

using this code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json(path_to_file, lines=True)
```

**Desired Output:** I want to create a new dataframe such that it has two columns

1. ID (unique identifier)
2. Sentence (Splitting in sentences the Contents column of df)

**What I have been able to do so far:**

Figured out that the tokenizer comes from **nltk**, and how to pass it to the **apply** function

```
  result = df["content"].apply(sent_tokenize)
```

My Question is how can I get the result in desired format as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use itertuples to iterate through dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['hi how are you. i am fine. hope this help you','ABC']], columns = ['sent','ID'])

 df
                                              sent  ID
 0   hi how are you. i am fine. hope this help you  ABC

new_sent =[]
for row in df.itertuples():
    for sent in sent_tokenize(row[1]):
        new_sent.append((sent, row[2]))

#creating dataframe for new_sent
df_new = pd.DataFrame(new_sent, columns = ['tokenized_sent', 'ID'])
#o/p

    tokenized_sent      ID
0   hi how are you.     ABC
1   i am fine.          ABC
2   hope this help you  ABC
```

explanation

```
for row in df.itertuples():
    print(row)

#o/p
Pandas(Index=0, sent='hi how are you. i am fine. hope this help you', ID='ABC')

print(row[0])
0

print(row[1])
'hi how are you. i am fine. hope this help you'

print(row[2])
'ABC'
```

Now we are performing tokenization on 2nd element and appending the sentence with it id on new_list

```
new_list = []
for sent in sent_tokenize(row[1]):
    new_list.append((sent, row[2]))
    print((sent, row[2]))

o/p
('hi how are you.', 'ABC')
('i am fine.', 'ABC')
('hope this help you', 'ABC')

# now  create dataframe with this new_sent
df_new = pd.DataFrame(new_sent, columns = ['tokenized_sent', 'ID'])
```

Comment: thanks for the help, could you add a bit of explanation to the code especially the nested for loop, how does `df_new` pick the right `ID`

Comment: @Imran Ali, added explanation... hope this work for you

Answer (score 0):

you can assign the return value of `apply` as a new column in your df,

```py
df["sentence"] = df["content"].apply(sent_tokenize)
```

and if you want to remove the other columns (Title and Content) you can also do it by assignment:

```py
df = df[["ID", "sentence"]]
```

Comment: May be I could not convey my point clearly.  I need the result of apply to span multiple rows e.g Row1 = 1, first sentence. Row2 = 1, second sentence, Row3=1, third sentence .... . Where number 1 represent Aritcle ID

Comment: @ImranAli Oh OK, sorry I didn't understand it correctly